# Does path.mkdir()'s updates the file permissions if path already exists and mode is passed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, chmod, docker-volume, 777

I have a volume attached in kubernetes with path `/var/www/aaa/tmp`.

That volume was created using [path.mkdir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir) and currently have `755` permissions.
It was created with code `path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)` initially.

I'm trying to update its permissions without deleting the existing path.

I'm using `path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True, mode=0o777)`. I'm still facing issues related to permissions and getting `502 Bad gateway` for the flask app that is creating the above directories.

Does the `path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True, mode=0o777)` updates the path permissions if it already exists and have `755` permissions? Or will it ignore it completely as we've mentioned `exists_ok=True` ? I don't see the permissions getting updated for the path.

Should I be deleting the path completely and re-running the `path.mkdir.....` with `mode=0o777` which creates new directories and set permissions?

**Edit 1:**
I've tried using `os.chmod()` on the path. But it's throwing `PermissionError`.

Here's the code snippet.

```
path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
os.chmod(path, mode=0o777)
```

**Error:**

> File "./app/**init**.py", line 79, in create_prediction_app
>        create_directories(app)    File "./app/**init**.py", line 36, in create_directories
>        os.chmod(path, mode=0o777)  PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/www/aaa/tmp'  unable to load app 0
>   (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)  *** no app
>   loaded. GAME OVER ***

Comment: Why not just use `os.chmod(...)`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chmod

Comment: @AlanSTACK Added PS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the path is already existing, you should use the `os.chmod(path, mode)` instead of deleting/re-creating.

**For example:**

```
import os

os.chmod("/var/www/aaa/tmp", 0o777)
```

Furthermore, the `chmod` can get the permission from `stat` module.

- stat.S_ISUID − Set user ID on execution.
- stat.S_ISGID − Set group ID on execution.
- stat.S_ENFMT − Record locking enforced.
- stat.S_ISVTX − Save text image after execution.
- stat.S_IREAD − Read by owner.
- stat.S_IWRITE − Write by owner.
- stat.S_IEXEC − Execute by owner.
- stat.S_IRWXU − Read, write, and execute by owner.
- stat.S_IRUSR − Read by owner.
- stat.S_IWUSR − Write by owner.
- stat.S_IXUSR − Execute by owner.
- stat.S_IRWXG − Read, write, and execute by group.
- stat.S_IRGRP − Read by group.
- stat.S_IWGRP − Write by group.
- stat.S_IXGRP − Execute by group.
- stat.S_IRWXO − Read, write, and execute by others.
- stat.S_IROTH − Read by others.
- stat.S_IWOTH − Write by others.
- stat.S_IXOTH − Execute by others.

**For example:**

```
import os
import stat

# Set a file write by others.
os.chmod("/var/www/aaa/tmp", stat.S_IWOTH)
```

You can set more permission with the bitwise operator.

**For example:**

```
import os
import stat

os.chmod(
    '/var/www/aaa/tmp',
    stat.S_IRUSR |
    stat.S_IROTH |
    stat.S_IRGRP 
)
```

**Complete testing:**

```
>>> touch test_perm.sh
>>> ll test_perm.sh
-rw-rw-r-- test_perm.sh
>>> python -c "import os; os.chmod('test_perm.sh', 0755)"
>>> ll test_perm.sh
-rwxr-xr-x test_perm.sh
```

**EDIT:**

If you get `PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:...` exception when you want to change the permission with `os.chmod`, you should try the following code part to solve it. It's important to run the script with admin rights (with `sudo` in Linux environment).

**Code:**

```
from getpwnam import pwd
from getgrnam import grp
import os

uid = getpwnam("USERNAME")[2]
gid = grp.getgrnam("GROUPNAME")[2]
os.chown("/var/www/aaa/tmp", uid, gid)
```

Based on the official `chown` documentation:

> os.chown(path, uid, gid, *, dir_fd=None, follow_symlinks=True)
>
> Change the owner and group id of path to the numeric uid and gid. To leave one of the ids unchanged, set it to -1.
>
> This function can support specifying a file descriptor, paths relative to directory descriptors and not following symlinks.
>
> See shutil.chown() for a higher-level function that accepts names in addition to numeric ids.
>
> Availability: Unix.
>
> New in version 3.3: Added support for specifying path as an open file descriptor, and the dir_fd and follow_symlinks arguments.
>
> Changed in version 3.6: Supports a path-like object.

Link to documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chown

Comment: There's a mistake in your first snippet. It should be `0o777` instead. Also, `0755` won't work in python3 anymore. `0o` is required.

Comment: For some reason it's granting `755` permissions even though I mentioned `mode=0o777`

Comment: I have edited my answer based on your PS. I have mentioned a possible solution to solve the `PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:...` exception.

Answer (score 0):

milanbalazs' answer is very nice, good explanation, but will only chmod the last directory in the path. In my case this was not good enough, because I needed to ensure every subfolder all the way down the last one was also chmodded.

I couldn't find any simple way to do this with existing bash tools, the only one close to what I needed with was `chmod -R` but I also didn't want to interfere without anything other than specifically each folder specified in the path.

To clarify, in the example, we have the path `/var/www/aaa/tmp`. I might want to start from `/var/www` and ensure that both `/var/www/aaa` and `/var/www/aaa/tmp` have their permissions set to whatever I want.

So I wrote the following script to solve this use case;

```
import os
import argparse

def base8(val):
    return int(val, base=8)

def path(val):
    assert os.path.exists(val)
    return val

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('start_dir', type=path, help='starting point for chmod to check for subdirectories')
    parser.add_argument('end_dir', help='last directory to be chmodded, relative to start_dir')
    parser.add_argument('permission', type=base8, help='permission to set on each directory (must be base 8 format e.g. "0o750")')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

def main():
    args = parse_args()

    directories = os.path.split(args.end_dir)
    current_dir = args.start_dir
    for directory in directories:
        current_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, directory)
        os.chmod(current_dir, args.permission)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Hopefully someone finds this useful one day :)